# Play Framework 2.2.0 Java Email

Tags: java, email, playframework-2.2, build-dependencies

I'm using the Play Framework 2.2.0 with java 7.4.

I've been trying all week to find an email module or package that I can use to send an email from my play application.  I have tried many different packages and each time I get either a package not found exception, a compilation error or package not found exception.

I have had many variations of the **Build.scala**, and the **Build.sbt**.  I also tried unmanaged dependencies and managed dependencies pulling from 'maven' I believe it's called and pulling from my /lib directory respectively.  The packages I have downloaded to my /lib directory are:

**commons-io-2.3**

**javax.mail**

**play-plugins-mailer_2.2.0**

My versions of my **Build.scala** have been:

**Build.scala**

**1st attempt**:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "Asset Manager"
    val appVersion      = "1.0"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
        "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
        "org.scala-tools" %% "scala-stm" % "0.3",
        "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.4.1.3" % "test",
        "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3.1",
        "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.3"
    )
}
```

**2nd attempt:**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    lazy val buildVersion = "2.2.0"
    lazy val playVersion = "2.2.0"

    val appName         = "Asset Manager"
    val appVersion      = "1.0"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
        "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
        "org.scala-tools" %% "scala-stm" % "0.3",
        "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.4.1.3" % "test",
        "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.3"
    )

    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3.1";
    libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-util" % buildVersion;

}
```

My Emailing Java File **Parts.java:**

**1st attempt**

```
package controllers;

import play.libs.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.commons.mail.*;

...

        SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setFrom(User.getByUsername(Session.get("username")).email);
        email.addTo(app.configuration().getString("ownerEmail"));
        email.addTo(part.email);
        email.setSubject("Part Added: " + part.vendor + " - " + part.label);
        email.setMsg("A Part has been added to the Asset Manager:\n\n"
            + part.toString());
        Mail.send(email);

...
```

**2nd attempt:**

```
package controllers;

import play.libs.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

import com.typesafe.plugin._;

...

            MailerAPI mail = play.Play.application().plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();
            mail.setSubject("test");
            mail.addRecipient("");
            mail.addFrom("");
            mail.sendHtml("A Part has been added to the Asset Manager:\n\n" + part.toString());

...
```

**3rd attempt:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

...

            String to = "...";
            String from = "...";
            String host = "localhost";
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

            // Get the default Session object.
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            try{
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));
                message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
                message.setText("This is actual message");

                // Send message
                Transport.send(message);
                System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
            }catch (MessagingException me) {
                me.printStackTrace();
            }
...
```

My question is how do I set up my Play Framework so that it doesn't tell me this:

```
**Compilation error**

error: cannot find symbol
In ..\app\controllers\Parts.java at line 116.

113            // mail.addFrom("");
114            // mail.sendHtml("A Part has been added to the Asset Manager:\n\n" + part.toString());
115
116            SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
117            email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
118            email.setSmtpPort(465);
119            email.setFrom("","");
120            // email.setFrom(User.getByUsername(Session.get("username")).email);
121            email.addTo("");
```

**note: I emptied out some strings that contained personal information.

Whenever I try to refresh my page.  I need to know where I put my package specific information, how the build.scala should look, whether the command order (../play clean; ../play dependencies; ../play run) is correct, whether I should be using managed or unmanaged and ultimately whether or not this is even possible!?!?

**Thanks all.**

Comment: I was using the sublime text 2 editor before.  So, I resolved this issue by setting up the newest version of eclipse.  I ran the eclipse command for play and imported via Play's documented steps.  It was a classpath issue.  However, now the emails still are not being sent and there are no error's being thrown...  Using the SimpleEmail object am I supposed to be able to send emails using localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the response.  I just solved it this morning!  The error was caused by my packages not being added to my path.  I highly recommend using a power IDE for classpath modifications.  I entered it into Eclipse and instantly I had my object reference's corrected.  For the mailer itself here's my results:

```
...

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

...

    try {
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String username = "program-email@gmail.com";
        String password = "password";
        InternetAddress[] addresses = {new InternetAddress("user@anymail.com"),
            new InternetAddress(bid.email),
            new InternetAddress("another-user@anymail.com")};
        Properties props = new Properties();

        // set any needed mail.smtps.* properties here
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSubject("my subject placed here");
        message.setContent("my message placed here:\n\n"
                + part.toString(), "text/plain");
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses);

        // set the message content here
        Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");
        try {
            t.connect(host, username, password);
            t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        } finally {
            t.close();
        }          
    } catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have multiple questions:

1. How to get play to work with email.

   - For this I suggest look at the play authenticate code and see how they make it work.  I'm currently using the module to send email. [play-authenticate](http://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/)
2. You may have an issue with getting email logs. Did you try looking at the system logs?  /var/log/syslog (for example on Ubuntu/Debian). There's also log configuration options for play [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SettingsLogger)
3. (Looks like you solved it?) You have a:

   **Compilation error**

   error: cannot find symbol
   In ..\app\controllers\Parts.java at line 116.

   - There's nothing really special about setting up paths for play as long as you have the play executable in the path.

Comment: The code I supplied was not complete so the error wouldn't have been accurate from what I provided here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer

It worked like a charm for me

Let me know if you have any questions